# Please help me understand the concept of variable, and differentiation of variables.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-derivative, differential

`I am in the first year of college and know mathematical analysis in a very rigorous context, from high school/ math olympiads Imo's etc. But the concept of $df$ seems totally weird and unmathematical.  For example if you have $$f(x_1,...x_n)$$ how can you talk about the partial derivative $\frac{δx_1}{δf}$ or how can you say $$df= \sum \frac{δf}{δx_i}dx_i$$
When $df$ by itself meens nothing. Also wy if $$f(x,y)=g(u,v)$$.  then $df=dg $. It seems so strange to work with functions with no argument.  Where can i learn this stuff in a rigorous way.
I even tried to view d/dx as an operator between the vector spaces of functions but still everything is unrigorous.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between $\delta x$ and $\mathrm{d}x$? Also if you did math olympiads then this should not be that difficult to understand.

Comment: Yes just didn't know how to put the symbol in latex. I changed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you updated your question.

Read what [Paul's Online Math Notes](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/PartialDerivatives.aspx) have to say on Partial Derivatives.

Your you can read section 5.3 of [Introduction to Real Analysis](http://ramanujan.math.trinity.edu/wtrench/texts/TRENCH_REAL_ANALYSIS.PDF) by Trinity University

Quoting the previous link

> Definition 5.3.1 Let $\Phi$ be a unit vector and $X$ a point in $\mathbb{R}^n$. The directional derivative of $f$ at $X$ in the direction of $\Phi$ is defined by
>
> $$ \frac{\partial f(X)}{\partial \Phi} = \lim\limits_{t \to 0} \frac{f(X+ t\Phi) - f(X)}{t} $$
>
> if the limit exists. That is, $\partial f(X)/\partial\Phi$ is the ordinary derivative of the function $h(t) = f(X+t\Phi)$ at $t=0,$ if $h^{\prime}(0)$ exists.

Read this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/619665/the-difference-between-delta-x-delta-x-and-dx) here on this site.

Or [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20171219234818/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/60949.html) on Dr. Math

Here a picture from [image: intuitive-calculus.com]

Hope that this gives you enough to read to understand.